# Jquery html() cannot convert all xhtml to html standard

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to grab html code from my site. I can do so using `html()` and I need to compare the string.

For example.

I get `< br/>` however it seems the browser or jquery only get `< br>` - without the closing slash.

I researched and found this http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4509

It seems that it can be resolved by serving the page as application/xml+xhtml. However, I can't get it working. Any expert advice appreciated.

Comment: The html you get back is browser dependent. You shouldn't be comparing the strings directly.

Comment: Hi, then how should i be doing. I need to compare the exact string that i grab from the site.

Comment: @Slay, comparing HTML is probably the solution you found to a specific problem. Since it is not going to happen nicely, you should rather tell us about the initial problem you're trying to solve, so maybe we can come up with another solution.

Comment: I am doing an app that allow users to grab content(html) from a site. After grabbing, i would need to store it in my database. Then, i would need to crawl my site, detect if there is any changes to the code, if there is, it will prompt me that my html code in my site changes. I could get all working, detection etc, however its the xhtml closing tag issue that is giving me issues.

If jquery return me <br> instead of <br/> my string comparison to check if there is any changes failed.

Comment: I just checked on firefox 4, chrome, IE, seems that jquery return me all tags withing self close. i am using this site as a reference ->http://www.lookhealthy.org/healthy-vs-white-teeth/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. For anyone who want to just something like $("#container").xhtml() , you can just this extension. http://code.google.com/p/jqxhtml/

This is for IE, alittle modification of it can caters for webkit browsers as well. Hope this can help anyone who need it in future.